# C# WPF Отображение на форме хода установки msi установщика

Tags: c#, wpf, windowsinstaller

Через мою программу запускается msi установщик. Есть ли способ отследить ход установки и вывести его на форму?

```
public void install_uninstall(string _targetIpAddress)
{
    //string _targetIpAddress = (string)PC;
    string[] directum = { "1.msi", "2.msi", "3.msi" };

    string retVal = "";

    ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();
    //options.Username = @"domain\username";
    //options.Password = "password";
    ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(("\\\\" + _targetIpAddress + "\\root\\cimv2"), options);
    scope.Connect();



    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher;
    SelectQuery query;
    EnumerationOptions enumOptions;
    ManagementPath p = new ManagementPath("Win32_Product");
    ManagementClass classInstance = new ManagementClass(scope, p, null);
    ManagementBaseObject inParams = classInstance.GetMethodParameters("Install");
    ManagementBaseObject outParams;
    inParams["AllUsers"] = true;
    inParams["Options"] = string.Empty;

    if (programs.Contains("1"))
    {
        thisTime = DateTime.Now;
        percent = 100 / 6F;

        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new ThreadStart(delegate { text_install.Document.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run(thisTime + " Удаление..."))); ProgressBar.IsIndeterminate = false; PercentText.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; }));


    thisTime = DateTime.Now;
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new ThreadStart(delegate { text_install.Document.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run(thisTime + " Установка..."))); }));

    foreach (var item in dir)
    {
        inParams["PackageLocation"] = @"\\" + _targetIpAddress + @"\d$\Dir\" + item;
        outParams = classInstance.InvokeMethod("Install", inParams, null);
        retVal = outParams["ReturnValue"].ToString();

        retVal_install(dir, inParams, retVal, item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Это, кажется, не связанные вопросы. Может их лучше отдельно задать?  Также было бы неплохо увидеть ваши попытки решить свои задачи

Comment: Согласен, вопросы немного несвязные. Если есть возможность кодом отслеживать ход установки msi установщика, то хотелось бы такое решение увидеть. Если нет, то мне подойдет решение с помощью обновления текста. К примеру, пока установка не вернет какое-то значение, то обновлять текст к примеру: "Установка." "Установка.." Установка...". Хочется это сделать для визуализации процесса.

Answer (score 2):

Можно. Для этого необходимо использовать [Windows Installer API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Msi/windows-installer-portal). Например, так можно вывести в TextBox действия и возникающие ошибки в ходе установки:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();   
        }

        const string msipath = "C:\\Distr\\1.msi";

        public int MyInstallUIHandler(IntPtr pvContext, uint iMessageType, string szMessage)
        {
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { textBox1.Text += szMessage + Environment.NewLine; });
            return 1;
        }

        public void InstallMsi(string msipath, bool uninstall)
        {
            string pars = "";
            if (uninstall) pars = "REMOVE=ALL"; 

            IntPtr ptr = IntPtr.Zero;
            InstallUIHandler handler = new InstallUIHandler(MyInstallUIHandler);

            //отключаем стандартный UI
            MsiSetInternalUI(INSTALLUILEVEL.INSTALLUILEVEL_NONE, ref ptr);

            //устанавливаем обработчик сообщений
            MsiSetExternalUI(
                handler,
                INSTALLLOGMODE.INSTALLLOGMODE_ACTIONSTART  | INSTALLLOGMODE.INSTALLLOGMODE_ERROR,
                IntPtr.Zero
                );

            //запускаем установку (удаление)
            MsiInstallProduct(msipath, pars);
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Task.Run(() => { InstallMsi(msipath, false); });            
        }

        enum INSTALLMESSAGE
        {
            INSTALLMESSAGE_FATALEXIT = 0x00000000, // premature termination, possibly fatal OOM
            INSTALLMESSAGE_ERROR = 0x01000000, // formatted error message
            INSTALLMESSAGE_WARNING = 0x02000000, // formatted warning message
            INSTALLMESSAGE_USER = 0x03000000, // user request message
            INSTALLMESSAGE_INFO = 0x04000000, // informative message for log
            INSTALLMESSAGE_FILESINUSE = 0x05000000, // list of files in use that need to be replaced
            INSTALLMESSAGE_RESOLVESOURCE = 0x06000000, // request to determine a valid source location
            INSTALLMESSAGE_OUTOFDISKSPACE = 0x07000000, // insufficient disk space message
            INSTALLMESSAGE_ACTIONSTART = 0x08000000, // start of action: action name & description
            INSTALLMESSAGE_ACTIONDATA = 0x09000000, // formatted data associated with individual action item
            INSTALLMESSAGE_PROGRESS = 0x0A000000, // progress gauge info: units so far, total
            INSTALLMESSAGE_COMMONDATA = 0x0B000000, // product info for dialog: language Id, dialog caption
            INSTALLMESSAGE_INITIALIZE = 0x0C000000, // sent prior to UI initialization, no string data
            INSTALLMESSAGE_TERMINATE = 0x0D000000, // sent after UI termination, no string data
            INSTALLMESSAGE_SHOWDIALOG = 0x0E000000 // sent prior to display or authored dialog or wizard        
        }

        enum INSTALLLOGMODE  // bit flags for use with MsiEnableLog and MsiSetExternalUI
        {
            INSTALLLOGMODE_FATALEXIT = (1 << (INSTALLMESSAGE.INSTALLMESSAGE_FATALEXIT >> 24)),
            INSTALLLOGMODE_ERROR = (1 << (INSTALLMESSAGE.INSTALLMESSAGE_ERROR >> 24)),
            INSTALLLOGMODE_WARNING = (1 << (INSTALLMESSAGE.INSTALLMESSAGE_WARNING >> 24)),
            INSTALLLOGMODE_USER = (1 << (INSTALLMESSAGE.INSTALLMESSAGE_USER >> 24)),
            INSTALLLOGMODE_INFO = (1 << (INSTALLMESSAGE.INSTALLMESSAGE_INFO >> 24)),
            INSTALLLOGMODE_RESOLVESOURCE = (1 << (INSTALLMESSAGE.INSTALLMESSAGE_RESOLVESOURCE >> 24)),
            INSTALLLOGMODE_OUTOFDISKSPACE = (1 << (INSTALLMESSAGE.INSTALLMESSAGE_OUTOFDISKSPACE >> 24)),
            INSTALLLOGMODE_ACTIONSTART = (1 << (INSTALLMESSAGE.INSTALLMESSAGE_ACTIONSTART >> 24)),
            INSTALLLOGMODE_ACTIONDATA = (1 << (INSTALLMESSAGE.INSTALLMESSAGE_ACTIONDATA >> 24)),
            INSTALLLOGMODE_COMMONDATA = (1 << (INSTALLMESSAGE.INSTALLMESSAGE_COMMONDATA >> 24)),
            INSTALLLOGMODE_PROPERTYDUMP = (1 << (INSTALLMESSAGE.INSTALLMESSAGE_PROGRESS >> 24)), // log only
            INSTALLLOGMODE_VERBOSE = (1 << (INSTALLMESSAGE.INSTALLMESSAGE_INITIALIZE >> 24)), // log only
            INSTALLLOGMODE_EXTRADEBUG = (1 << (INSTALLMESSAGE.INSTALLMESSAGE_TERMINATE >> 24)), // log only
            INSTALLLOGMODE_LOGONLYONERROR = (1 << (INSTALLMESSAGE.INSTALLMESSAGE_SHOWDIALOG >> 24)), // log only    
            INSTALLLOGMODE_PROGRESS = (1 << (INSTALLMESSAGE.INSTALLMESSAGE_PROGRESS >> 24)), // external handler only
            INSTALLLOGMODE_INITIALIZE = (1 << (INSTALLMESSAGE.INSTALLMESSAGE_INITIALIZE >> 24)), // external handler only
            INSTALLLOGMODE_TERMINATE = (1 << (INSTALLMESSAGE.INSTALLMESSAGE_TERMINATE >> 24)), // external handler only
            INSTALLLOGMODE_SHOWDIALOG = (1 << (INSTALLMESSAGE.INSTALLMESSAGE_SHOWDIALOG >> 24)), // external handler only
            INSTALLLOGMODE_FILESINUSE = (1 << (INSTALLMESSAGE.INSTALLMESSAGE_FILESINUSE >> 24)), // external handler only
        }

        public enum INSTALLUILEVEL
        {
            INSTALLUILEVEL_NOCHANGE = 0,    // UI level is unchanged
            INSTALLUILEVEL_DEFAULT = 1,    // default UI is used
            INSTALLUILEVEL_NONE = 2,    // completely silent installation
            INSTALLUILEVEL_BASIC = 3,    // simple progress and error handling
            INSTALLUILEVEL_REDUCED = 4,    // authored UI, wizard dialogs suppressed
            INSTALLUILEVEL_FULL = 5,    // authored UI with wizards, progress, errors
            INSTALLUILEVEL_ENDDIALOG = 0x80, // display success/failure dialog at end of install
            INSTALLUILEVEL_PROGRESSONLY = 0x40, // display only progress dialog
            INSTALLUILEVEL_HIDECANCEL = 0x20, // do not display the cancel button in basic UI
            INSTALLUILEVEL_SOURCERESONLY = 0x100, // force display of source resolution even if quiet
        }

        [DllImport("msi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]        
        static extern uint MsiInstallProduct(string packagePath, string commandLine);

        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Winapi, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public delegate int InstallUIHandler(
            IntPtr pvContext,
            uint iMessageType,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string szMessage);

        [DllImport("msi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
        static extern uint MsiSetExternalUI(InstallUIHandler puiHandler, INSTALLLOGMODE dwMessageFilter,
           IntPtr pvContext);

        [DllImport("msi.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern int MsiSetInternalUI(INSTALLUILEVEL dwUILevel, ref IntPtr phWnd);        
    }    
}
```

Пример вывода:

```
Action 10:11:18: INSTALL. 
Action 10:11:18: ValidateProductID. 
Action 10:11:18: CostInitialize. Computing space requirements
Action 10:11:18: FileCost. Computing space requirements
Action 10:11:18: CostFinalize. Computing space requirements
Action 10:11:18: InstallValidate. Validating install
Action 10:11:18: InstallInitialize. 
Action 10:11:18: GenerateScript. Generating script operations for action:
Action 10:11:18: ProcessComponents. Updating component registration
Action 10:11:18: MsiUnpublishAssemblies. Unpublishing assembly information
Action 10:11:18: UnpublishFeatures. Unpublishing Product Features
Action 10:11:18: RemoveRegistryValues. Removing system registry values
Action 10:11:19: RemoveFiles. Removing files
Action 10:11:19: InstallFiles. Copying new files
Action 10:11:19: WriteRegistryValues. Writing system registry values
Action 10:11:19: RegisterUser. Registering user
Action 10:11:19: RegisterProduct. Registering product
Action 10:11:19: MsiPublishAssemblies. Publishing assembly information
Action 10:11:19: PublishFeatures. Publishing Product Features
Action 10:11:19: PublishProduct. Publishing product information
Action 10:11:19: InstallFinalize. 
Action 10:11:19: InstallInitialize. 
Action 10:11:19: ProcessComponents. Updating component registration
Action 10:11:19: MsiUnpublishAssemblies. Unpublishing assembly information
Action 10:11:19: UnpublishFeatures. Unpublishing Product Features
Action 10:11:19: RemoveRegistryValues. Removing system registry values
Action 10:11:19: RemoveFiles. Removing files
Action 10:11:19: PublishProduct. Publishing product information
Action 10:11:20: RollbackCleanup. Removing backup files
```

Информацию о том, какие события Windows Installer можно обрабатывать, см. в документации по [MsiSetExternalUI](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/msi/nf-msi-msisetexternaluia)

Comment: Спасибо за пример. Но я так понимаю здесь локальная установка. С помощью wmi возможно использовать Windows Installer API?

Comment: @patrik Нет, Windows Installer API работает только локально. Насколько я знаю, при удаленной установке через WMI передается только команда на запуск MSI, информация о ходе установки не передается, т.к. это приводило бы к слишком большим объемам сетевого трафика. Но если вам это действительно нужно, можно вынести этот функционал в консольное приложение и запускать его удаленно через [PsExec](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec), перехватывая в WPF его вывод.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию